# Test Class for Android

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, android

I have a HttpRequestActivity Class which makes a call  to  the  server from  the android Application. I have to  write a test case for this class to check whether the received string is a JSON string.How should i do this .I have tried to implement the method

```
public class HttpRequestActivityTest extends
android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase<HttpRequestActivity> {
```

It gives error that HttpRequestActivity is not an activity and thus cannot be a parameter for the ActivityUnitTestCase which is correct.But I cannot write a plan Java JUnit testCase as this class imports an android import  "import android.os.AsyncTask;"

What should be the approach ?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class HttpRequestActivity {

public String url_str, response_str = "";
HttpClient client;
JSONObject json;

public HttpRequestActivity(String targetUrl, String proxyHost) {
    if (!proxyHost.equals("")) {
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
    }
    url_str = targetUrl;
}

public String getResponseString() throws InterruptedException,
        ExecutionException, IOException {
    ResponseString response = new ResponseString();
    return response.execute(url_str).get();
}

public class ResponseString extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url_str);
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url_str);

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
            HttpEntity e = response.getEntity();
            response_str = EntityUtils.toString(e);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response_str;
    }

}

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
package com.yourpackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.util.Log;

/**
 * This class sends your data through GET and POST methods
 * 
 * */
public class HttpRequest {

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient;
    HttpContext localContext;
    private String ret;

    HttpResponse response = null;
    HttpPost httpPost = null;
    HttpGet httpGet = null;
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Map.Entry me;
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Iterator i;

    public HttpRequest() {
        HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 50000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 50000);
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(myParams);
        localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    }

    public void clearCookies() {
        httpClient.getCookieStore().clear();
    }

    public String sendGet(String url) {
        httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            ret = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("HttpRequest", "" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public String postData(String url, List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs)
            throws Exception {
        // Getting the response handler for handling the post response
        ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();
        HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(url);

        // Setting the data that is to be sent
        postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        String response = httpClient.execute(postMethod, res);
        return response;
    }

}
```

now for calling this from your activity do this:

```
final HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String json;
            try {
                 json = httpRequest.sendGet("url");


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }).start();
```

Now for return json check whether it is valid or not. Thanks.